# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Tags: python

```
numOfYears = 0
cpi = eval(input("Enter the CPI for July 2015: "))
if cpi.isdigit():
    while cpi < (cpi * 2):
        cpi *= 1.025
        numOfYears += 1
    print("Consumer prices will double in " + str(numOfYears) + " years.")
while not cpi.isdigit():
    print("Bad input")
    cpi = input("Enter the CPI for July 2015: ")
```

I'm getting the following error.

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Since I'm new to programming, I don't really know what it's trying to tell me. I'm using the `if cpi.isdigit():` to check to see if what the user entered is a valid number.

Comment: Why not use `int(input(...))` which will convert string to int

Comment: Can you provide more information like 
What is the value you are passing?
What is your python version?
What is the stacktrace?

Comment: I'm entering an integer "239" but when someone else runs the program, they should be able to enter an int or a float.

Comment: Additional this code has a huge [Arbitrary code execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) vulnerability due to it `eval`ing user input, which could contain python code.

Comment: This code will loop forever, unless `cpi` is negative, because a non-negative number is less than itself times two by basic rules of math.

Comment: In the condition "while cpi < (cpi * 2)", is there any way I can get the number that the user enters to double its self without having an infinite loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
numOfYears = 0
# since it's just suppposed to be a number, don't use eval!
# It's a security risk
# Simply cast it to a string
cpi = str(input("Enter the CPI for July 2015: "))

# keep going until you know it's a digit
while not cpi.isdigit():
    print("Bad input")
    cpi = input("Enter the CPI for July 2015: ")

# now that you know it's a digit, make it a float
cpi = float(cpi)
while cpi < (cpi * 2):
    cpi *= 1.025
    numOfYears += 1
# it's also easier to format the string
print("Consumer prices will double in {} years.".format(numOfYears))
```

Comment: aka, just wrap with str( )

Answer (score 7):

As documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) `isdigit()` is a string method. You can't call this method for integers.

This line,

```
cpi = eval(input("Enter the CPI for July 2015: "))
```

`evaluates` the user input to integer.

```
>>> x = eval(input("something: "))
something: 34
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> x.isdigit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

But if you remove `eval` method (you should better do that),

```
>>> x = input("something: ")
something: 54
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> x.isdigit()
True
```

everything will be fine.

by the way using eval without sanitizin user input may cause problems

consider this.

```
>>> x = eval(input("something: "))
something: __import__('os').listdir()
>>> x
['az.php', 'so', 'form.php', '.htaccess', 'action.php' ...
```

Comment: But you still didn't explain what will happened when running `cpi *= 1.025` and `cpi` is `str`...

Comment: it will spit TypeError, then he will edit the question, and will ask "I have another issue" :)

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
if(str(yourvariable).isdigit()) :
    print "number"
```

`isdigit()` works only for strings.

Comment: isdigit() will not work with negative numbers. It does not see the - as a digit and returns false. To solve that you can simply use this... yourString.replace("-","").isdigit()

Answer (score 0):

[`eval()` is very dangerous!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) And `int()` built-in function can convert string to digit.

If you want to catch the error if user didn't enter a number, just use `try...except` like this:

```
numOfYears = 0

while numOfYears == 0:
    try:
        cpi = int(input("Enter the CPI for July 2015: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Bad input")
    else:
        while cpi < (cpi * 2):
            cpi *= 1.025
            numOfYears += 1

print("Consumer prices will double in", numOfYears, "years.")
```